# Receive attachment with urllib - Python

Tags: python, http, urllib

I am testing my webpage software by sending requests from python to it. I am able to send requests, receive responses and parse the json. However, one option on the webpage is to download files. I send the download request and can confirm that the response headers contain what I expect (application/octet-stream and the appropriate filename) but the Content-Length is 0. If the length is 0, I assume the file was not actually sent. I am able to download files from other means so I know my software works but I am having trouble with getting it to work with python.

I build up the request then do:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
f.body = f.read()
```

I expect data to be in f.body but it is empty (I see "b''")

Is there a different way to access the file contents from an attachment in python?

Comment: Why are you writing this back into your request object? Why not `body = f.read()`, say?

Comment: I write it back to the object so that I can simply return one object with all of the information to a calling function. I suppose the calling function cause do f.read()....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to throw some data into the file in order to have something in the body. I should've noticed this much sooner.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a different way to access the file contents from an attachment in python?

This is in [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead `urllib`, since I'm more familiar with that.

```
import requests

url = "http://example.com/foobar.jpg"

#make request
r = requests.get(url)
attachment_data = r.content

#save to file
with open(r"C:/pictures/foobar.jpg", 'wb') as f:
  f.write(attachment_data)
```

Comment: Thank you. I may use this module when I try to upload files now.